# Using Python to find and change attribute in an XML file

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have been trying to figure out how to change the price for the plant "Greek Valerian" using the percent change and in the range `-90 < percentChange < 100`.

I can find and manually change names and numbers, I just can't figure out how to use the percent change, and am using Py Charm community edition. The `outputt.xml` file in my code is the second file I'm writing my changes to.

My XML snippet is:

```
<PLANT>    
    <COMMON>Greek Valerian</COMMON>    
    <BOTANICAL>Polemonium caeruleum</BOTANICAL>    
    <ZONE>Annual</ZONE>
    <LIGHT>Shade</LIGHT>    
    <PRICE>4.36</PRICE>    
    <AVAILABILITY>071499</AVAILABILITY>    
</PLANT>
<PLANT>    
    <COMMON>California Poppy</COMMON>    
    <BOTANICAL>Eschscholzia californica</BOTANICAL>
    <ZONE>Annual</ZONE>    
    <LIGHT>Sun</LIGHT>   
    <PRICE>7.89</PRICE>    
    <AVAILABILITY>032799</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>
```

The Python3 code I've got thus far is:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

with open('plant_catalog.xml', encoding='latin-1') as f:
  tree = ET.parse(f)
  root = tree.getroot()

  for elem in root.getiterator():
    try:
      elem.text = elem.text.replace('4.36', '5')
    except AttributeError:
      pass    
tree.write('outputt.xml', encoding='latin-1')
```

Can anyone help me solving this?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the price to

```
current_price*(1+percentChange/100)
```

First find the plant that you're interested in:

```
for plant in root.iter('COMMON'):
    if plant.text!='Greek Valerian':
        continue
    else:
        price = None
        for i in range(4):
            price = plant.getnext()
        price.text = str(float(price.text)*(1+percentChange/100))
```

Comment: Thanks, would I just want to replace the line elem.text = elem.text.replace('4.36', '5') with this?

Comment: Thanks and I replaced my old for statement with the new for statement and still get an error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Hewitts/PycharmProjects/pythonproject2/xmlparse.py", line 13, in <module>
    price = plant.getnext()
AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'getnext'

Comment: @Clancy please, try to change `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET` to `import lxml.etree as ET`